# Make a simple join to a reference table with Laravel 5.1 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple join to make, but I can't do it.

I have a tournament that has a categoryId field in the table.

The table TournamentLevel is a 10 entry table.

So I would like to be able to retrieve level->name with Eloquent.

I tried to do the following:

In Tournament, I tried to define a hasOne relationship:

```
class Tournament extends Model
{
....
    public function level()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\TournamentLevel');
}
```

But then, Eloquant is looking for tourmanent_id inside of TournamentLevel Table

So I tried the opposite,

In Model TournamentLevel:

```
class TournamentLevel extends Model
{
...

public function tournament()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tournament');
}


}
```

And tried to reach :

```
tournament->level->name
```

but without success

It seems pretty elementary, but I can't do it... Any idea???

Comment: What's the exact problem? Do you get any error? Or maybe you want to get join but 2 queries are executed and that's your problem?

Comment: I need to reach the name associated to the Id, but I can't. For instance, levelId 1 = local, so I would like to get "local" by tournament->level->name. Right now, I get an Id

Comment: **But then, Eloquant is looking for tourmanent_id inside of TournamentLevel Table** well, it's the case. Eloquent `hasOne` expect the related model - in your case `TournamentLevel` - to have a `foreign key` to the `Tournaments` and named `tournament_id`. if you already have a `foreign key` specify it, look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

Comment: Yes I understand, but thing is my table is for reference only, it has only 2 field : id - name. There is no point to associate a tournament here, so I guess the relation is not the good one.

Comment: well i want to clarify basically, `TournamentLevel` had one-to-many relationship to `Tournaments`? **ps** i'm wondering about your statement: *I have a tournament that has a categoryId field in the table.*

Comment: 1 Tournament has only 1 Level, but 1 Level can have many Tournaments

Comment: well, you could use a `hasMany(...)` from `TournamentLevel` to `Tournament`. this way you can still access tournamentlevel's name if you defined `belongsTo(..)` in `Tournament`.

Comment: But a tournament doesn't not belong to a tournamentLevel... A tournament should belong to a user, this would be ok, a tournament hasOne level, but then laravel tell me he need a tournament_id inside tournamentLevel :(

Comment: tbh, `hasOne` and `belongsTo` just define the one who holds the `foreign key`. so do `hasMany`-`belongsTo` or `hasMany`-`belongsToMany`, so, it's not a real problem when accessing the model. and a tournament belong to a user is a different thing about `TournamentLevel` to `Tournament` relations. just consider a user as a friend of your friend. perhaps, before start make relations, you should draw ERD somewhere first.

Comment: unless your foreign key in the `TournamentLevel` table is called `tournament_id`, you will need to specify it as a parameter  for the relationship function you use. Eloquent expects the foreign key to be the name of the parent table with `_id` concatenated on the end.

Comment: I have the opposite. a FK level_id in tournament table.

Comment: your relation from `TournamentLevel` should be looked like `return $this->hasMany('App\Tournament', 'level_id', 'id');` then, from Tournament, you had `return $this->belongsTo('App\TournamentLevel', 'level_id', 'id')`. it's on the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). or, if you insist to *tournament **has** level and only **belong** to user*, you could do this from `Tournament`, `return $this->hasOne('App\Tournament', 'id', 'level_id');` - i won't suggest this, it'll make headache later, trust me :)

Comment: it worked! Please put your comment as answer so that I accept it! I still don't understand why should a tournament belongs to a tournament level....but anyway... I'm learning! Tx for your help!